# Typescript object property when defining object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to infer an object property during the creation of an object. I have the following interface.

```
interface Config {
  comp: ComponentType<any>;
  props: any;
}
```

I can successfully create a config.

```
const config: Config = {
  comp: MyComponent;
  props: {
    prop1: 3,
    prop2: "test"
  }
};
```

How would I enforce the props object to use the props defined in the component itself?

```
const config: Config[] = [
  {
    comp: MyComponent,
    props: {
      prop1: 3,
      prop2: "test"
    }
  },
  {
    comp: AnotherComponent,
    props: {
      anotherProp: false
    }
  }
];
```

How would I then also enforce the same rules for an array, where each config can have a different component?

I've attempted using generics and using the infer keyword, but having difficulty getting this to work.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

In the last example, I'd expect **const config** to be typed as a tuple, and look something like this:

```
[
  {
     comp: MyComponent,
     props: ExtractPropsTypeOf<MyComponent>
  },
  {
     comp: AnotherComponent,
     props: ExtractPropsTypeOf<AnotherComponent>
  }
]
```

Comment: Let me just check I’m understanding your question correctly - you want to use an object *at runtime* as a template to enforce type on another object?

Comment: Not at runtime, I'd like the config to be able to infer the type of props, from the component type. The definition of the config constant wont be changing. I'll edit the post and add an example of what I'm expecting from the type.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example of how React expects to received typed props:

```jsx
export interface CaptionProps {
  children: string;
}

export interface CaptionState {
}

export default class Caption extends React.Component<CaptionProps, CaptionState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<CaptionProps>) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return <div className="caption">{ this.props.children }</div>;
  }
}
```

If you declare your components like this, you *should* be able to use this syntax:

```ts
interface Config<Props> {
  comp: React.Component<Props, any>;
  props: Props;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, making config generic alone wont work. In the array example, I'd have to declare **cont config** with the type **Config<any>[]**. Therefore, I lose the props type when declaring them, as props is always **any**. I'm hoping to infer the type of config from the component that is used. Similar to how you can extract react prop types from a component using the **infer** keyword.